# Annual summation for each category

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, categories, rows

[image]
I have a datafarme as shown in the image below.

Answer (score 0):

with `data.table` it would be something like:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(Year = c(2016, 2016, 2015), TF = c("Import", "Export", "Export"), value = c(123, 456, 789))
dat[, .(`total export` = sum(value[TF == "Export"]), `total import` = sum(value[TF == "Import"]), total = sum(value)), by = Year]
```